# Is it all right to treat Discount Policy as an entity in my ER diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, diagram, erd

I'm trying to build my first ER diagram for store management. One of the requirement is that each `Customer type` is associated with one `discount policy` and depending on which type a `customer` belongs to, the associated `discount policy` will be applied to his bill. The discount policy is percentage-based. Right now I'm treating `Discount Policy` as an entity and have the attribute `Percentage Discount Based On Policy` on the relationship between Discount Policy and Bills.

Here's my ER diagram (where "`Discount Policy`" is a separate entity): [image]

My question is: If each `Customer Type` has their own `Discount Policy`, is it better for me to make `Discount Policy` an attribute of `Customer Type`? And is it okay to put an attribute on a relationship? I'm new to data modelling, so I'm pretty confused whether an item should be an entity or an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In E-R modelling relationships don't have attributes.  If you have an attribute in your model which 'belongs' to a 'relationship' then that 'relationship' is properly an entity.  To take an easy example, one might imagine that a 'marriage' is a relationship between two 'person's, but what if you want to record the 'date' of the marriage?  Then it must be an entity in its own right with relationships to the two persons involved.

If your discount policy is really customer specific, so that you don't have, say, a discount policy for small customers, a discount policy for large customers, or a discount policy for customers overseas, etc, then perhaps it is a set of attributes on the customer entity.  I suspect, though, that you will probably find on deeper analysis that the discount policy should be an entity and that it has a M:N relationship with customers.

Comment: Based on your explanation, I think it's better to keep discount policy as an entity. And where should I put Percentage Discount, since it both depends on bill and discount policy. I mean, the discount policy will take the bill value into account and then decide how much that bill will be discounted (percentage-based). So, I don't know if it should be an attribute of discount policy or bill.

Answer (score 0):

In Chen's ER modeling, relationships can have attributes as well, as he explained in his [foundational paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/320434.320440):

> Note that **relationships also have attributes**.  Consider the relationship PROJECT-WORKER (Figure 3). The attribute PERCENTAGE-OF-TIME, which is the portion of time a particular employee is committed to a particular project is an attribute defined on the relationship set PROJECT-WORKER.  It is neither an attribute of EMPLOYEE nor an attribute of PROJECT, since its meaning depends on both the employee and the project involved. The **concept of attribute of relationship is important in understanding the semantics** of data **and determining the functional dependencies** among data.

So it is perfectly valid to model the `Discount Policy` as an entity related to a `Customer Type`, if this is the reality in your domain.   Your model could answer questions such as:  "what does each discount policy costs, and what is the related turnover?".  You didn't indicate cardinality,  but if a `Customer Type` could be associated with several policies, this model would also allow to implement some more complex business rules, for example that is several policies apply, only the most beneficial is taken into account.

On the other side, this model might be unnecessarily complex, if in reality, you only calculate a fixed discount rate for every bill, based on the customer type. In this case, make it an attribute of the customer type. You just have to be aware that this modeling would be more restrictive and could not be used for more dynamic policies such as scaled discount (e.g. up to $500, it's 1% discount, form $501 to $2000, it's 3% and over $2000 it's 5%)

So there is no ultimate best solution: it only depends on the meaning you intend to give to your data.